# Python Library and Parent References in Import statements

Tags: python, import

I am building my first Library from scratch and I have come up with an interesting problem.

My Folder structure is looking like the following:

```
Tools/
  __init__.py
  connector1/
    __init__.py
    connector1.py
  connector2/
    __init__.py
    connector2.py
```

I was looking at the source code of Pandas and using my folder structure as a reference I saw that they could do an import in connector2.py using `from Tools.connector1 import connector1`.

How can I do the import using the parent directory in the reference to access connector1?

At the moment I have not fully loaded into into pip and still importing it from the Parent directory with the hopes to soon load it into my environment.

I am hoping that I will be able to import the module for connector1 from connector2. I have tried to include the imports of the classes into the `__init__` in the Tools Director.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret your question as asking how `connector2` can access `connector1` using relative, instead of absolute, imports.

Instead of

```
from Tools.connector1 import connector1
```

use

```
from .connector1 import connector1
```

The `.` refers to the current package, which for the package module `connector2` is `Tools`. `.connector1` is then a module named `connector1` in the current package, i.e. `Tools.connector1`.

Loosely speaking, `.foo` is a "sibling" module, in the same package as the module doing the import.

Answer (score 0):

You import modules from the current package with

```py
from . import foo
```

You can import modules from the directory above the current package using

```py
from .. import foo
```

In your case, you might use

```py
# File: connector1/connector1.py
from .. import connector1
```